# jsonp callback data in highcharts not working

Tags: node.js, highcharts, jsonp

using nodejs and jsonp, trying to fig out highcharts but its not working, beow code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $.getJSON('http://myserverhere.com:3010/?f=GBP&t=USD&callback=?', function (data) {
    alert("hey");
    console.log(data);
    // create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
      rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
      },
      title: {
        text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
      },
      navigator: {
        enabled: true,
        height: 25
      },
      series: [{
        type: 'candlestick',
        name: 'AAPL Stock Price',
        data: data,
        dataGrouping: {}
      }]
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

below is my server.js in nodejs

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
var port = 3010;
var path = "C:\\mypath\\";
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'
    });
    return res.end();
  }
  var query = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
  var urlString = {
    pathname: url.parse(req.url).pathname,
    queryparam: url.parse(req.url, true).query
  };
  var file = query.f + query.t;
  var gbpusd;
  fs.readFile(path + file + '_M1.json', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    //console.log(data);
    gbpusd = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log("query param");
    console.log(urlString.queryparam.callback);
    if (urlString.queryparam.callback && urlString.queryparam.callback != '?') {
      console.log("in if block");
      gbpusd = urlString.queryparam.callback + "(" + gbpusd + ");";
    }
    //console.log(eurusd);
    res.writeHead(200, {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'content-lenght': gbpusd.length
    });
    //res.write(JSON.stringify(gbpusd));
    var p = JSON.stringify(gbpusd);
    res.end(p);
  });
}).listen(port);
console.log("server running at port 3010..");
```

its a simple highchart candlestick, i am trying to work with my jsonp data. 
console log the data as well returning jsonp function successfully but in highchart call back its not working, even alert is not running.
i can smell there is some problem with node res.end() or the way node is returning data, dont know but just a calcuated guess.
any one please.

Comment: code formating is not good in SO, i wrote this in my previous post as well but no one to hear!!

Comment: nothing in console, no errors but chart is not populating

Comment: Better to post your JSON results and not your server code - we don't know what is being produced.

Comment: thanks Rijvi for the reply its [[dateinseconds,open,high,low,close],..], like below:[[1378088520,1.55159,1.55159,1.55157,1.55157],[1378088580,1.55156,1.55159,1.55156,1.55157],[1378088640,1.55156,1.55163,1.55155,1.55159],...]  these are exactly the same like produced in highstock candlestick example, the problem is highstock is not rendring my jsonp data

Comment: more on this, browser can see the data i mean i can return the data to the browser but its not working in highstock candlestick example dont know why.

Comment: also when i am returning the result, data imean, in res.end(gbpusd) without Json.stringify IT is giving me error "Too many arguments in function call (only 32766 allowed)" when i am using stringify its gone

Answer (score 0):

ok i solved it finally, it was the placement of stringify which was wrong, data should be stringified first before it get wrapped in jsonp call ie before below call, and that make sense otherwise callback function will be stringifie'd. and that was the mistake and my code breaks

```
if(urlString.queryparam.callback && urlString.queryparam.callback != '?'){
        console.log("in if block");
        gbpusd = urlString.queryparam.callback + "(" + gbpusd + ");";       
    }
```

also first i am parsing the data using JSON.parse() and then used stringify.
var parseddata = JSON.parse(data);
gbpusd = JSON.stringify(parseddata);